# Beacon Layout for MPact Beacon

Tags: android, ibeacon, ibeacon-android, altbeacon, beacon

I have [MPact beacon](https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/US-EN/Wireless+Networks/Wireless+LAN/MPact+Locationing+Solutions/MPact_US-EN).

I can't find appropriate layout to altbeacon library.

I try some predefined layouts and beacons were found only when I used IBEACON layout `("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24")`.

I don't know if it appropriate for MPact beacon too...

Comment: The layout for iBeacon is a very common implementation.  If it works to detect, it is probably the correct choice.

Answer (score 0):

I was exploring the MPact Android SDK and came around the following code:

`setBeaconLayout("m:0-1=2a00,i:2-3,i:4-5,p:6-6");`

Also, given that MPact uses the very Altbeacon library, it's very likely that the provided layout will work.